# FX option trading questions

Tags: fx, delta-hedging, delta-neutral

1. Are all FX trades ( RR, BF, ATM)quoted in implied vol term delta neutral trades?
2. If trades are not delta neutral at the initiation does that mean it is speculative trading? Why/ why not?

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, in the sense that it is assumed that the delta will be passed between participants at time of execution.
2. Not necessarily.  A non delta neutral trade may be used for speculation , or for hedging.

Comment: 1. Can you please explain "Delta will be passed at the time of execution"?

Comment: Well let’s say there is a ATM FX option trade where 2 banks agree to trade at a volatility of 10%.  Now they have to translate it into a price.  So they plug it into their Black model.  However they first agree the level of the underlying spot rate and the amount of delta hedging that is required to make each delta neutral. For example 25pct delta at 1.2056 fx rate.  This delta is then passed between the two participants.  If they didn’t pass the delta,  each would have to trade the delta in the market , which could incur slippage causing the implied vol to be different from 10%.

Comment: It’s a bit confusing to refer to an ATM option with a 25 delta.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor can you also please share your views on the above questions. As usual you may have different ways of explaining this as well. Thanks.

Comment: @christaylor, good point obviously I should have used 50 delta in the example.

Comment: @dm63 thank you for your explanation. It really helped a lot.

Comment: I am afraid I did not understand: 1. if the two banks trade delta seperately in market how will this cause slippage of the implied vol. 2. What if after trading they are not willing to trade delta? They might carry open delta position.

Comment: 2. If the trade is consummated in volatility terms, it is implicitly agreed that there will be a delta exchange.   1.  Suppose bank A calculates an option price of 1.27 using an underlying fx rate of 1.2056.  If, for some reason, the option trade is done at 1.27, but the delta is not exchanged, bank A would have to execute the delta on the spot market.  They might get 1.2053.   But the implied vol if the option price is 1.27 and the underlying is 1.2053 is , say , 10.1%.  Not what was agreed.  The point is , if you are trading pure vol , you must eliminate all the other exposures.